# Writing to video memory in VGA mode 13h

Tags: assembly

I'm using NASM to learn x86 assembly, running my code in qemu on linux.
I am trying to draw a pixel on the screen.

Why is it that

```
mov     bx,0xA000 
mov byte [bx],0x0A
```

doesn't seem to do anything, but

```
mov     bx,0xA000 
mov     es,bx 
mov byte [es:di],0x0A
```

is able to draw a pixel?

A second question: Why do I have to use [es:di] rather than just [es]?

Comment: Many of the old assembly howtos no longer apply. Protect mode computing prevents direct hardware access, such as moving bits to/from the VGA buffer on modern OS's. If you are running an old version of DOS, you can still make it work.

Comment: (A) It is because you're trying to write to location 0xA inside the 64kb chunk of memory your program is running in (known as a segment). Assuming your segment is 0x1000, you'll be trying to write to 0x1000:0x000A (segmented address), which is (0x1000 << 4) + (0x000A) = 0x10000A - absolute byte address. I.e it's byte index 65546 - so you're writing to the 10th byte of the second segment. You need to write to the 655360th byte of memory, which is absolute address 0xA0000, which is 0xA000:0000

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : As long as you have your GDT set up so that the lower 1mb of RAM is accessible then you can surely write to those same video locations when in protected mode. I'm assuming though we are dealing with a baremetal environment where we have our own OS. If we are a userland application in something like Linux then direct hardware access would not be allowed without some special allowance by the kernel.

Answer (score 8):

In real mode, an address used for reads and writes consists of a segment and an offset, and the actual address read from or written to is calculated as `segment * 16 + offset`.

*Note: In documentation, etc; the segment and offset are typically as written 2 numbers joined by a colon (like 0x1234:0x5678, where 0x1234 is the segment and 0x5678 is the offset)*.

For 0x0000:0xA000 the actual address is 0x0000A000. This address typically corresponds to RAM.

For 0xA000:0x0000 the actual address is 0x000A0000. This is where the legacy VGA display memory area is (which is used when video cards emulate ancient VGA's 320 * 200 video mode).

All reads and writes use a segment register, and if you don't specify one explicitly (e.g. `mov [es:di],ax`) then the CPU uses a default/implied segment register, which is normally `DS` (unless `SP` or `BP` is being used for the offset part of the address which makes `SS` the default/implied segment, or its instruction fetch which always uses `CS`). This means that `mov [di],ax` does the same as `mov [ds:di],ax`.

The offset part is always explicit and the CPU doesn't support (e.g.) "offset is assumed to be 0x0000 as default". This means you can't do `mov [es],ax` because there is no offset (and no way to encode the instruction) and you'd have to do something like `mov [es:0x0000],ax` instead.